# How to disable TListView edit on item click?

Tags: delphi, edit, delphi-6, tlistview

I want to disable entering edit mode when I click on a TListView selected item but not disable it completely (setting property ReadOnly=True). I want to still be able to edit it by other methods. It is possible ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't see any easy way to detect precisely how the `LVN_BEGINLABELEDIT` notification arises. And it's the `LVN_BEGINLABELEDIT` notification that triggers in-place edit of the list view.

So, I think you'll probably need to come up with a slightly hacky solution. Add a `Boolean` field to your form, named `FCanEditListView` for example. Then wherever you trigger edit mode, set this flag `True` just before you trigger edit mode, and then revert it to `False` afterwards:

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  Item: TListItem;
begin
  Item := ListView1.Selected;
  if Assigned(Item) then
  begin
    FCanEditListView := True;
    Item.EditCaption;
    FCanEditListView := False;
  end;
end;
```

Then add a handler for the `OnEditing` event of the list view, to switch behaviour as so:

```
procedure TForm1.ListView1Editing(Sender: TObject; Item: TListItem;
  var AllowEdit: Boolean);
begin
  AllowEdit := FCanEditListView;
end;
```